# The value of $ \int _{0}^{1}x^{99}(1-x)^{100}dx $ is

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, factorial

The value of $\int _{0}^{1}x^{99}(1-x)^{100}dx $ is

Not able to do. I'm trying substituton. But clear failure. Please help.

Comment: You could expand, and integrate term by term...

Comment: There have been similat questions to this before on this site

Comment: That's really will make it hard. Its a MCQ. I was hoping some easy non tedious approach to solve it.

Comment: @Arjang  I joined this amazing forum just 2 days back. and I looked for the suggestions they show when question is being posted, I didnt find anything remotely close. So if its asked please link to such questions. And I apologise for asking a duplicate

Comment: @NS : was not having a go at you, just letting you know. And of course I might be wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just repeatedly integrate by parts:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^{99}(1 - x)^{100}\,dx &= {99 \over 101} \int_0^1 x^{98}(1 - x)^{101}\,dx \\
&= {99 \over 101} {98 \over 102} \int_0^1 x^{97}(1 - x)^{102}\,dx \\
&= {99 \over 101} {98 \over 102} {97 \over 103} \int_0^1 x^{96}(1 - x)^{103}\,dx \\
&\cdots \\
&= 99! {100! \over 199!} \int (1 - x)^{199}\,dx \\
&= {99! \,100! \over 200!}
\end{align}

Answer (score 15):

Let

$$I(n,m)=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^mdx$$
then by integration by parts we get

$$I(n,m)=\frac m{n+1}I(n+1,m-1)$$
and by induction we have

$$I(n,m)=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}I(n+m,0)=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Comment: Wow. That's the type of answer I was looking for. Really thankful @Sami.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Denote $B(r,s) = \int_0^1 x^{r-1}(1-x)^{s-1}\ dx$. Then your integral is $B(100,101)$, which is just the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

So your integral is just $\frac{99! 100!}{200!}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\int_0^1x^{99}(1-x)^{100}dx=B(100,101)=\frac{99!100!}{200!}$

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds :D

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use $I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$I+I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

Then set $x=\sin^2\theta$

Comment: I tried this way. Its getting more jumbled. Another hint? @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

This answer is due to T. Bayes known as *Bayes Billiard Balls* where he tells nice stories to establish:

$$\int_0^1 {n\choose{k}}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Therefore 
$$\int_0^1 {199\choose{99}}x^{99}(1-x)^{199-99}dx=\frac{1}{199+1}$$thus
$$\int_0^1 x^{99}(1-x)^{100}dx=\frac{99!100!}{199!}\frac{1}{200}=\frac{99!100!}{200!}$$

Comment: Are you not missing a summation behind the binomial? How else can the equality (first) hold?

Comment: This is a reformulation of the beta function :-) But the interpretation by Bayes is interesting ...